# enabling extglob with ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

is there any way to enable extglob from ansible?

```
- name: copy files
  sudo: yes
  shell: shopt -s extglob
```

but I got error:

```
failed: [host] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "shopt -s extglob", "delta": "0:00:00.001410", "end": "2015-10-20 09:10:36.438309", "rc": 127, "start": "2015-10-20 09:10:36.436899", "warnings": []}
stderr: /bin/sh: 1: shopt: not found

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I need extglob to be on to run this command. this command excluding directory `vendor` from being copied.

```
cp -pav --parents `git diff --name-only master feature/deploy_2186 !(vendor)` /tmp/current
```

The command is running properly from terminal, but not from ansible task. and after reading some article, it needs to enable extglob, so I can use `!(vendor)` pattern to exlcude vendor directory.

error when run copy from ansible task

```
failed: [host] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cp -pav --parents `git diff --name-only master new_release !(vendor)` /tmp/current", "delta": "0:00:00.003255", "end": "2015-10-20 09:22:16.387262", "rc": 1, "start": "2015-10-20 09:22:16.384007", "warnings": []}
stderr: fatal: ambiguous argument '!': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
cp: missing destination file operand after '/tmp/current'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

my ansible task to do copy, which if I remove `!(vendor)` it works perfectly but it has vendor inside:

```
- name: copy files
  shell: cp -pav --parents `git diff --name-only master feature/deploy_2186 !(vendor)` /tmp/current
  args:
    chdir: /var/www
  tags: release
```

Comment: Are you running the `cp` command from a shell task too?

Comment: How do you want to call the cp command? Can you make it part of a .sh script?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes I run cp from shell task to. I update my question.

Comment: @yacc i run cp from shell task. i update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways you can address this.

1) Put the command into a shell script `copy.sh` and set `shell: copy.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
cp -pav --parents `git diff --name-only master feature/deploy_2186 !(vendor)` /tmp/current
```

2) Use `grep -v` instead of extglob:

```
shell: cp -pav --parents `git diff --name-only master feature/deploy_2186 * | grep -v /vendor/` /tmp/current
```

3) Use bash to set extglob and run the cp command. You need to pass two separate lines to the ansible task variable. Since the syntax is Yaml it boils down to embed a newline in the shell string. Test it yourself.

```
shell: |
  bash -c 'shopt -s extglob
           cp -pav --parents `git diff --name-only master feature/deploy_2186 !(vendor)` /tmp/current'
```

or

```
shell: "bash -c 'shopt -s extglob \n cp -pav --parents `git diff --name-only master feature/deploy_2186 !(vendor)` /tmp/current'"
```

Comment: hi, I use the 2nd option and works, just i put `vendor` without backslash. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do something like this so that the `shopt` and `cp` commands are actually run within the same shell instance:

```
- name: copy files
  sudo: yes
  shell: shopt -s extglob && cp -pav --parents `git diff --name-only master feature/deploy_2186 !(vendor)` /tmp/current
```

Comment: shopt is a bash builtin while Ansible uses a basic shell (think `/bin/sh` vs `/bin/bash`) so I don't think this will work (although I haven't tested it)

Comment: This won't work with bash because it will try to parse the whole line before the extglob command is in effect and thus croak on `!(vendor)`

Comment: I've tried that and did not work also, it returned same error `stderr: /bin/sh: 1: shopt: not found`