# failed to delete multiple folders inside one folder except 3 folders using rm

Tags: shell, rm

I am trying to delete all folders inside a folder except 2 3 using rm. But, command doesnt work with below error
[image]

[image]

Tried using escape character, but it will not delete folders.

[image]

Any solutions?

EDIT 1

[image]

Using double quotes after parentheses is a not working

EDIT 2

using shopt is also not working

[image]

Comment: I have 15000 folders in my prod setup. I want to delete 14997 out of them. It will take too much time to delete them sequentially

Comment: Are you not able to use `find`? This seems like an ideal case for it or some other combination of list of files to delete to xargs with rm.

Comment: find can delete files, but when it comes to delete, we cant usevfind

Answer (score 0):

**Note 1**: Shell Option needs to be set first for extglob.  I had the same issue running my script until I added it to my .sh file.  Link below is a reference from Unix stack exchange.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file

**Full Working Script: test.sh**

```
shopt -s extglob;
cd Test;
rm -rfi !("atest3"|"atest2")
```

**Note 2**: If working in Ansible, the default shell is SH vs BASH.  Due to this, you may need to call the script with BASH or use solutions found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232582/enabling-extglob-with-ansible) to get it working.  The script below works in BASH. In ZSH it may require a setopt command similar to extglob.

[Script call from SH basic terminal using bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMN1d.png)

The following command will remove (**rm**) by force (**f**) recursively (**r**) and interactively (**i**) all files or folders except (**! bang operator**) for the file or folders strings (**'arg1'|'arg2'|...**) listed as piped (**|**) arguments.

If a nested files and folders is passed as an arg, but the parent is not, that file or folder will be deleted:

```
rm -rfi !('atest2'|'atest3')
```

[Example of using rm with -rf flags and bang operator to prevent passed string arguments being deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sebs0.png)

I am leaving the below commands as examples from an earlier answer I wrote.

This command will create multiple folders:

```
mkdir {test1,atest2,atest3,atest4}
```

And this command will remove the folders:

```
rm -rfi {test1,atest2,atest3,atest4}
```

[Example of mkdir with args and rm -rfi with args shell command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvMIL.png)

Comment: I want to delete all folders except test1,atest2,atest3. Basically, I want to ignore these folders to get deleted. Want to delete all others folder.
In my final task I have 15000 other folders and I want 14997 to be deleted in one go. Something like that

Comment: Ahh! You are looking for anti-pattern matching.  I'll modify my answer to match, but you can use rm -rfi !("atest4"|"atest2"|"test1")

Comment: rm -rf !() will be best option for me.

Comment: See the latest answer for what you are looking for! Have a great day 

Comment: pls check edit 1. Double quotes after parentheses didnt work in bash case

Comment: I didn't even think about shell args! Yeah, parentheses aren't allowed in shell scripts by default but if you do "shopt -s extglob;" at the start of your script it should work with " or ' quotes

Comment: thanks for your suggestions but shopt is not helping in our scenario. Pls check EDIT 2.

Comment: What shell are you running? I'm not super familiar with Ansible, so it may be something related to that environment.  Could you run 'bash' to execute the script? From what I'm seeing online, Ansible uses basic SH by default (old shell) instead of BASH (Bourne Again SHell).  Try 'bash ./test.sh'

Comment: Did running the script with BASH work for you?